# ¿Cómo mezclar dos CLASS en una imagen?

Tags: html, css, imagen, class, animación

Tengo dos 'css' donde cada uno da una acción diferente a las imagenes, y lo que quiero es saber si se pueden unir las dos en una línea de código, o hacer otra 'class' donde las mezcle.
Una es **zoom** que la descargue de internet es de zoomy.css, esta 'class' hace que si le doy click a mi imagen aparezca el efecto lupa de la misma.

El otro efecto, no sé como llamarlo. Lo que hace es que tengo imagenes chicas y al darle click aparecera a la derecha una imagen de la misma mas grande.

Lo que quiero es mezclar los efectos, es decir, primero que aparezcan las imagenes pequeñas, lo doy click aparece la grande y en esa darle click y salga el efecto lupa

```
   <ul class="cat">
            <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="min" src="../images/bici_noche.jpg" alt="#" />
                        <img class="max" src="../images/bici_noche.jpg" alt="#" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">

                        <?php echo '<img class="min" src="'.$imag1.'" >'; ?>
                    <div id="zoom"> <?php echo '<img class="max" src="'.$imag1.'" >'; ?>
                     </div></a>
                </li>

   </ul>
```

Este mi código, la primera parte es de las imagenes pequeñas a la grande.

```
    <?php echo '<a href="'.$imag1.'" class="zoom"><img src="'.$imag1.'"  width="200" heigth="50"></a>'; ?>
```

Este es del zoom

Este es el código del estilo de las pequeñas a grandes:

```
                        #contenedor {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto; }


        li .min {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 6px 20px 20px 7px;
            }
        li .max{
            width: 350px;
            height: 350px;
            padding: 6px 20px 20px 70px;
        }
        .cat    {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0 0 25px 10px; /* Eliminacion de vieta en IE6 */
            padding: 0px; /* Eliminacion de vieta en IE6 */
            float:left;
            }

        .max{
            visibility:hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 330px; /* Provoca la separacion del borde superior */
            left: 15%;  /* Separa la imagen grande de la pequea */
          margin-left: 0px;
            }

        a:focus .max    {
            visibility: visible;
            }
```

Y este es del zoomy

```
            /*
        * Zoomy 2.0.0 - jQuery plugin 
        * http://zoomy.me
        *
        * Copyright (c) 2010 Jacob Lowe (http://redeyeoperations.com)
        * Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt)
        * and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
        *
        * Built for jQuery library
        * http://jquery.com
        *
        * Addition fixes and modifications done by Larry Battle ( blarry@bateru.com )
        * Code has been refactored and the logic has been corrected.
        *
        *Cusor fix from IE by Chris Pearson ( http://www.upland.co.uk )
        *
        */
        body{
            -webkit-touch-callout: none!important;
        }

        .parent-zoom{
            -webkit-user-select: none!important;
        }

        .parent-zoom img{
            -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
            cursor:  cell;
            cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
            cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
            border: 0;
        }

        .zoomy{
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
            -o-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
            -ms-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=1, Color='#3333333', Positive='true');
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #fff;
            z-index: 999;
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: url(./img/blank.cur), move;
            -webkit-transition-property: border-width, border-color, opacity;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms, 1s, 500ms;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
        }

        .zoomy span{
            display: block;
            margin: 5px auto;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* firefox */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,.6)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* webkit */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#55FFFFFF, endColorstr=#00ffffff);
            -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#55FFFFFF, endColorstr=#00ffffff);
        }


        .zoomy a{
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
            outline: 0;
        }

        .inactive img{
            opacity: 0.85!important;
            filter:alpha(opacity=85)!important;
        }

        .zoomy #tmp{
            max-width: none;
            max-height: none;
            top: -999999px;
            left: -999999px;
        }

        .zoomy.start{
                border-width: 2px;
                border-color: #444;
        }

        .zoomy-wrap{
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            z-index: 999;
        }

        .zoomy-btn{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 60px;
            width : 60px;
            overflow: hidden;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.8);
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.8);
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
            background-position: 0px 0px;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
            line-height: 100px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .zoomy-btn svg{
            margin: 8px auto;
            display: block;
        }

        .active .zoomy-btn svg{
            display: none;
        }

        .active .zoomy-btn{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            border: none;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        }
```

Quise ponerlo así, pero no sale, simplemente no sale la imagen GRANDE y si le cambio el 'href' tampoco me sale:

```
                <li>
                    <a href="#">

                        <?php echo '<img class="min" src="'.$imag2.'" >'; ?></a>
                         <?php echo '<a href="'.$imag2.'" class="max zoom"><img src="'.$imag2.'"  width="200" heigth="50"></a>';  ?>

                </li>
```

¿Cómo lo puedo mezclar para que me salga esa galería?

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner dentro de la etiqueta **class**  las dos clases de css? al al estilo: class="clase1 clase2"

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he entendido lo que quieres es juntar los 2 estilos que tienes en las imágenes, en ese caso lo que tienes que hacer es dar el nombre de las 2 clases a las imágenes separados por un espacio, en tu ejemplo sería:

```
<a href="#">
       <img class="min zoomy" src="../images/bici_noche.jpg" alt="#" />
       <img class="max zoomy" src="../images/bici_noche.jpg" alt="#" />
</a>
```

Y aquí tienes un ejemplo ejecutable para ver como quedaría:

```css
.grande {font-size:40px;}
.rojo {color:red;}
```

```html
<p class="grande rojo">Un párrafo grande y rojo</p>
```

Comment: gracias, pero aun no me salio

Comment: gracias, pero aun no me salio
. veo que es un poco mas complicado que es. por lo que es el MIN Y MAX, al inicio en el href='#'  y en el ZOOM se redireccionana a la misma imagen. href='.$imag1.'. y al ponerlos  asi

                    <a href="#">
       <img class="min zoomy" src="../images/bici_noche.jpg" alt="#" />
       <img class="max zoomy" src="../images/bici_noche.jpg" alt="#" />
</a> 
no sale el efecto zoom por que se debe redireccionar asi misma para agrandarse